# Max retries exceeded with url and certificate verify failed while using Python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I am currently doing the python 100 days of code course and at Day 33 I just copied the code:

```py
import requests

my_lat = 51.507

my_long = -0.1277

parameters = {
    "lat": my_lat,
    "lng": my_long
}

response = requests.get("https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json", params=parameters)
response.raise_for_status()

data = response.json()

print(data)
```

When I do it I get:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.sunrise-sunset.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /json?lat=51.507&lng=-0.1277 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1129)')))
```

Anyone know why it isn't working? I have been looking around and nothing seems to fix it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: requests.get("https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json", params=parameters, verify=False)
replace with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because the site's certificate is expired. You can modify the code as below to bypass verification.

Also make a note that you shouldn't do this with untrusted sites.

```py
import requests

my_lat = 51.507

my_long = -0.1277

parameters = {"lat": my_lat, "lng": my_long}

response = requests.get(
    "https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json", params=parameters, verify=False
)
response.raise_for_status()

data = response.json()

print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Anyone know why it isn't working?

I tried opening https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/ in `firefox` and got warning about invalid or expired certificate. This is failure on server side and you (as client) are not in power to fix it. You might inform admin of said page about that issue, who might be able to fix it.

You might elect to avoid validation, by giving `verify=False` i.e.

```
response = requests.get("https://api.sunrise-sunset.org/json", params=parameters,verify=False)
```

but keep in mind this is workaround about said problem rather than proper fix.